# Merging dataframes on multiple conditions with date range

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes, based off two conditions. First, column A must match, followed by column B, with a range of 3 days. Meaning for df_a, the first date of 29-08-2019, I want it to match the the value in column B of df_b if it is between 26-08-2019 to 01-09-2019.

```
df_a

A             B             C
Alpha        29-08-2019     100
Beta         28-08-2019     150
Delta        15-07-2019     100
Alpha        24-07-2019     200
Beta         01-06-2019     100
Delta        30-06-2019     300
Gamma        07-05-2019     150

df_b   

A             B              C    
Alpha        01-09-2019      120
Beta         26-08-2019      130
Delta        14-07-2019      120
Alpha        25-07-2019      150
Beta         01-06-2019      120
```

I've tried a very simple merge, but got returned an empty dataframe.

```
merge = df_a.merge(df_b)
mask = (df_a['B']-df_b['B']).abs().dt.days<3
merge = merge.loc[mask, :]
```

To illustrate this is the expected result:

```
df_final

A             B             C       C (from df_b)
Alpha        29-08-2019     100     120
Beta         28-08-2019     150     130
Delta        15-07-2019     100     120
Alpha        24-07-2019     200     150
Beta         01-06-2019     100     120
Delta        30-06-2019     300     NaN
Gamma        07-05-2019     150     NaN
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand from where you get "28-08-2019 " in df_final?

Comment: @J.K sorry, updated it properly now

Comment: I also didn't understand the logic of the date between. In df_final, column B is the same as column B in df_a. Can you change the dates, so I can see how the logic supposed to work, or you explain it in another way.